# python selenium is running after OS upgrade

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, windows-11

My code worked smoothly before i upgraded my OS and after upgrading and installing python, selenium, putting chrome driver where it supposed to be, here's the error.

```
File "C:\Users\PiNgInG\Documents\Extension\betWay_Auto.py", line 16, in <module>
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver, options=options)

File "C:\Users\PiNgInG\Documents\Extension\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
super(WebDriver, self).__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",

File "C:\Users\PiNgInG\Documents\Extension\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 93, in __init__
RemoteWebDriver.__init__(

File "C:\Users\PiNgInG\Documents\Extension\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 266, in __init__
self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)

File "C:\Users\PiNgInG\Documents\Extension\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 357, in start_session
response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)

File "C:\Users\PiNgInG\Documents\Extension\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 418, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)

File "C:\Users\PiNgInG\Documents\Extension\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at localhost:1111
from chrome not reachable
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
Ordinal0 [0x00793AB3+2505395]
Ordinal0 [0x0072AE41+2076225]
Ordinal0 [0x00632360+1057632]
Ordinal0 [0x006273AD+1012653]
Ordinal0 [0x00650174+1180020]
Ordinal0 [0x00649FEB+1155051]
Ordinal0 [0x00649DD1+1154513]
Ordinal0 [0x0067A02F+1351727]
Ordinal0 [0x00679C9A+1350810]
Ordinal0 [0x006758BB+1333435]
Ordinal0 [0x006523E4+1188836]
Ordinal0 [0x0065323F+1192511]
GetHandleVerifier [0x0091CB36+1554566]
GetHandleVerifier [0x009C4A0C+2242396]
GetHandleVerifier [0x00820E0B+523099]
GetHandleVerifier [0x0081FEB0+519168]
Ordinal0 [0x007302FD+2097917]
Ordinal0 [0x00734388+2114440]
Ordinal0 [0x007344C2+2114754]
Ordinal0 [0x0073E041+2154561]
BaseThreadInitThunk [0x75EA6739+25]
RtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x77398AFF+1215]
RtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x77398ACD+1165]
```

Before the upgrade, the code runs fine, after the upgrade same code brings up this lengthy error.

**I upgraded to windows 11.** Could that be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to realize after installation of the new OS, I downloaded Chrome Browser which downloads the latest version but I was making use of the chrome driver from my previous OS which version isn't the same as the new Chrome Browser.

I fixed the error by updating my driver.

For example, my Chrome Browser is version "105.0.0", i downloaded driver verion "105.0.0".